# When I run my app in Xcode it crashes when I press a button with sound attached to it

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4.4

So am making this app where if you press a button, a sound plays but when i pressed the button the app crashed. Heres me code

In the .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

}

-(IBAction)buttonPressedWithSound:(id)sender;

@end
```

nothing wrong there, But in the .m file

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressedWithSound:(id)sender {

int randomSoundNumber = arc4random() % 4; //random number from 0 to 3

NSLog(@"random NR = %i", randomSoundNumber);

NSString *effectTitle;

switch (randomSoundNumber) {
    case 0:
        effectTitle = @"Come at me BRO!";
        break;
    case 1:
        effectTitle = @"sound2";
        break;
    case 2:
        effectTitle = @"sound3";
        break;
    case 3:
        effectTitle = @"sound4";
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

SystemSoundID soundID;

NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:effectTitle ofType:@"caf"];
NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID ((CFURLRef)CFBridgingRetain(soundUrl), &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}

@end
```

this line here

```
 NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
```

well it said there was something wrong with it, this

```
 2012-08-10 10:12:52.419 Sound +[1177:907] random NR = 1(lldb)
```

and

```
 NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
```

had a green highlight and said "Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1"  to the side of it.

How can i fix it and can it to play the sound without crashing

Comment: also does anyone know better code for the .m file, i dont want it to play more then one sound, only 1 sound per button

Comment: NSLog your soundPath. It may be invalid.

Comment: so do i change soundpath to NSLog?

Comment: No, you do NSLog(@"%@",soundPath) after you set soundPath's value.

Comment: Do you actually have a file called 'sound2.caf' being packaged into your app's main bundle?  (Click on your target, then look at the Copy Bundle Resources part of the Build Phases tab.)

Comment: Are you testing on device or on simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the NSSound class:

```
NSSound *sound = [[[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: soundPath byReference: NO] autorelease];

[sound play];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code logged what you asked it to and then hit a breakpoint that you set in the code.  Hit the continue button.

Comment: if it was then please post the stack trace from the console

Comment: i did put a break point, i dont know anything about them though i just seen it on a website